# Get specific column value from MySql in Laravel DB select function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How to I get a specific column value after fetching the results from MySql in Laravel DB select function

Below is my php code.

```
$list = DB::select('SELECT DISTINCT a.pincode FROM table_name nvs 
        JOIN areas a on nvs.area_id = a.id 
        where nvs.city_id = ?;', [$area_id]);
```

Below is the results for above query.

```
[
  {
    "pincode": "560005"
  },
  {
    "pincode": "560006"
  }
]
```

I need only pincode value not as key value pair. So i tried with the below code.

```
return array_column($list->toArray(), 'pincode');
```

It gives **Call to a member function toArray() on array**.

How can I get only values without using foreach loop.

**Answer**

I used the below code

```
$pincode_list = DB::table('table_name as nvs')
            ->join('areas as a', 'nvs.area_id', '=', 'a.id')
            ->select('a.pincode')
            ->where('nvs.city_id', '=', $area_id)
            ->distinct('a.pincode')->pluck('pincode')->toArray();
```

**Result was :**

```
[
    "560067",
    "560035"
]
```

Comment: use pluck for single values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way is to use Query Builder or Eloquent and use this instead of `get()`:

```
->pluck('pincode')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the query should be like

```
 $area_ids = DB::table('table_name')
        ->join('areas', 'nvs.area_id', '=', 'table_name.id')
        ->select('table_name.pincode')
        ->where('nvs.city_id', '=', $area_id)
        ->distinct()->get();
```

and if you are getting it as object and want it to be array you can use `toArray()` here like `$area_ids = $area_ids->toArray();` can you please test it and let me know the new status.

Comment: @Sharath check https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins if you are writing core PHP PDO query why you are usiing Laravel ?

Comment: Now i am using laravel functions instead of PDO query

Comment: @Sharath if you found my answer helpful, you should have upvoted it .

Answer (score 0):

```
$all_pincodes = array_values ($list);
```

But I suggest using Laravel Eloquent as you are anyway using Laravel so it's better to use in-build functionalities to ease the process.

Answer (score 0):

Using your variant:

```
\DB::setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = \DB::select($yourQuery);
$pincodes = array_pluck($data, 'pincode')
\DB::setFetchMode(config('database.fetch')); //return fetch to default
```

Using more fluent way:

```
  $pincodes = \DB::table('table')->pluck('pincode')->toArray(); //do not forget about wheres and joins in this query.
```

I would recommend you second variant because this is more clear way to get result what you need.